# How to display all the values of a particular element under the element name?

Tags: xml, xslt

Raw Xml:

```
<section sectiontype="WITNESSES">
                    <bodytext>
                        <p>
                            <text>
                                <person:person>
                                    <person:name.text>NEIL CAVUTO, FBN ANCHOR</person:name.text>
                                </person:person>
                            </text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>
                                <person:person>
                                    <person:name.text>REP. BARNEY FRANK, D-MASS.</person:name.text>
                                </person:person>
                            </text>
                        </p>
                    </bodytext>
                </section>
```

XSL template I have:

```
<xsl:template match="base:section[@sectiontype='WITNESSES']/base:bodytext/base:p">
    <xsl:element name="nl"/>
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">           
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="display">block</xsl:attribute>             
        <xsl:element name="hdr">
            <xsl:attribute name="typestyle">BF</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="inline">Y</xsl:attribute>  
            <xsl:text>WITNESSES:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>                      
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Current Output I get:

WITNESSES:                                                                                                                        NEIL CAVUTO, FBN                                                ANCHOR
WITNESSES:                                                                                                                        REP. BARNEY FRANK,                                                D-MASS.

Desired Output:

WITNESSES:

NEIL CAVUTO, FBN ANCHOR

REP. BARNEY FRANK, D-MASS.

Answer (score 0):

You have presented one template, which matches certain <base:p> elements.  It is instantiated separately for each element it is matched to, and each instantiation creates a text node in the result tree with value "WITNESSES", followed by a transformation of the element's children.  If you want to group the witnesses under one heading, then, you need to output the heading via a transform of a common ancestor element of those `base:p` elements.

For example,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:base="http://my.com/base"
    xmlns:person="http://my.com/person">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//base:section"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="base:section[@sectiontype='WITNESSES']">
    <xsl:text>WITNESSES:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//person:name.text"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person:name.text">
    <xsl:text>&#x10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It worked great! thanks. 

But the my Desired Output is:

WITNESSES: 
NEIL CAVUTO, FBN ANCHOR
REP. BARNEY FRANK, D-MASS.

And what I'm getting is:

WITNESSES:                                                                                                 NEIL CAVUTO, FBN ANCHOR                                                                                                                 REP. BARNEY FRANK, D-MASS.

Comment: @JohnDev, No difference between your desired and observed output made it through the comment.  In any event, there are factors beyond XSLT affecting how your results are presented in various media.  Since you did not disclose the presentation medium or process, all I can do is explain the principle.  You have to figure out what ***XML*** output you need from your transform, and apply the information I've given you to produce that.